# How to skip table sorting in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

As the default setting the table showed unsorted. If I eventually click any column the table will be sorted by ascending of this column. Everything what I can do later on is to pick another column or change the ordering direction (from ascending to descending and vice versa)

I can not figure out how to skip ordering at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the phpMyAdmin home page, go to *Settings > Main panel > Browse mode* (or *Settings > Main frame* for old versions), and uncheck the option *Remember table's sorting*, then click *Save*.

Then when browsing a table you can sort the columns as usual, but clicking *Browse* again will remove the sorting.

Tested on versions 3.5.2.2 and 4.0.10.14.

Comment: Everything were as you described! Thanks! Sorry - I can upvote as my reputation is almost clear.

Comment: What about version 4.5 ?  I don't see the setting.

Comment: If `Browse mode` is not available in the tabs, click on the gear icon at the top right of the right-side column instead of gear icon in the left side menu column. Hope this may help someone.