# PhpMyAdmin column search

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I import a table into my PHPmyadmin the  it is well done and the coulmns in the view is ok. But in the left column of Phpmyadmin is the table-columns in alfabetic order. Where is the parameter to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

From the phpMyAdmin home page, go to Settings > Main panel > Browse mode (or Settings > Main frame for old versions), and uncheck the option Remember table's sorting, then click Save. Then when browsing a table you can sort the columns as usual, but clicking Browse again will remove the sorting.

[How to skip table sorting in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037385/how-to-skip-table-sorting-in-phpmyadmin)